# ThinkTecture IdentityServer on Azure

Tags: azure, iis-express, thinktecture-ident-server

I used the following guide to set up IdentityServer for deploying to Azure: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2013/01/running-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-in-a-windows-azure-web-role-from-zero-to-hero-a-walkthrough.html

I got all the way until actually running the Azure site locally, but when I attempt to start it, I receive a 500.19 error in IIS Express.

[image: Screen capture of IIS error]

I have googled this error endlessly, but every solution has failed.  Oddly, if I start IISExpress for the WebSite from the Command Prompt, I'm able to visit the site without issue.  I'm certain this is an issue with the Azure Emulator, but I'm not sure how or why...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have you tried running your site in local full IIS?